# PHPBB & PHP Debug hiding

Tags: php, debugging, phpbb

I want to know if there is a way for hide phpbb debug infos using a php code, for example, when I search for a certain username that dont exist in my mysql database I get lots of phpbb debug alerts. For example I get: `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` because the username doesnt exist and I want to hide this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your config.php file make sure the last two lines of code are commented out so they look like this:

```
// @define('DEBUG', true);
// @define('DEBUG_EXTRA', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do `error_reporting(0)` or `ini_set('display_errors', 'off')` at the top of your script.